# Volume device disk mount docker compose error - not a directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to mount a disk using docker-compose.

Currently I can assemble using `docker service create`, this way:

```
docker service create -d \
 --name my-service \
 -p 8888:80 \
 --mount='type=volume,dst=/usr/local/apache2/htdocs,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=xfs,volume-opt=device=/dev/sdd' \
 httpd
```

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  my-service:
    image: httpd
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: my-vol
        target: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs

volumes:
  my-vol:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: xfs
      o: bind
      device: '/dev/sdd'
```

When uploading the service with `docker-compose up` I get the error:

```
"failed to mount local volume: mount /dev/sdd:/var/lib/docker/volumes/apache_my-vol/_data, flags: 0x1000: not a directory"
```

How can I configure my `docker-compose.yml` to be able to mount a disk?

*Sorry, my bad english..

Comment: `o: bind` isn't appropriate for trying to mount a physical disk.  Does removing that help?

Comment: Yes, it did! Thank you very much David!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `o:` line matches options you'd pass to the ordinary Linux **mount**(8) command.  `o: bind` manually creates a *bind mount* that attaches part of the filesystem somewhere else; this is the mechanic behind Docker's bind-mount system.  The important thing that changes here is that it causes the `device:` to actually be interpreted as a (host-system) directory to be remounted, and not a device.

Since you're trying to mount a physical device, you don't need the `o: bind` option.  If you delete that option, the `device:` will be interpreted as a device name and you'll be able to mount your disk.